# How do you logout using the latest Expo Google Auth API?

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo

The log in mechanism works as shown here:

https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#google

But, there is no log out functionality listed or shown in the example.

How do you log out?

Answer (score -1):

For google auth use https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/ instead of Authentication